# DWM windowManager for Windows, command?

Tags: windows, window-managers, dwm

I am using dwm for Windows now:
http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/dwm-win32/

Regularly I use it in Linux where I can use `mod+I` and `mod+D` to change between vertical and horizontal layouts.

In the Windows version that doesn't work for me, and I can't find any other command for the function. Does anyone know how it can be achieved? It's a great and fast windowManager. ^_^

Comment: The project page promises "serious bugs".  Open source projects like this only get somewhere when other devs, like you, fix those bugs and submit the patches.

Answer (score 0):

I came in contact with the developer, and the function wasn't implemented in the windows clone.